# AWS SNS Response Link to JavaMail

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jakarta-mail

I have sent my mail through java mail and registered my email on Amazon to get the response notifications (Bounce, Delivered) etc.

How can i succesfully match these two to say when i have sent the mail, the mail i sent has the following incomming response.

Note: Everything is setup (Webhooks to get the response from AWS SNS)

I tried matching it by the messageId, but it seems aws adds a different messsageId than the java mail one. Example

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.getMessageID(); // returns "<1619401941.3.1560500581268@Tinus-NB>"
```

And the from the AWS SNS response

```
"MessageId" : "7cd42bc4-e5c2-576b-a567-7eb9baa51cad" // directly
"Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Delivery\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2019-06-14T08:38:55.113Z\",\"messageId\":\"0102016b5523c189-55acd572-ba3f-4750-aaae-b7019080f1ae-000000\",\"delivery\":{\"timestamp\":\"2019-06-14T08:39:03.043Z\",\"processingTimeMillis\":7930,\"smtpResponse\":\"250 2.0.0 OK  1560501543 f15si1572805ede.113 - gsmtp\"}}" // this is in the Message object in the JSON
```

Just to be clear, I want to match these two, to know what i sent and what the response was.

I am using Java Mail and not the AWS SDK lib

Answer (score 1):

SES overwrites MessageID whatever you set because it also needs to know which email is it. In your case, when sending emails from Javamail,in the last section of your code, you can print the 250 response code+ message ID from SES and match it with the message ID you received from SNS.
When SES accepts an email in SMTP conversation, it gives 250 ok+ message ID and the same message ID can be seen in SNS notification.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, i just had to include the original headers

[image]